# Как у дробного числа откинуть целю часть и округлить до n чисел?

Tags: javascript

Вычислите дробные части чисел a и b с точностью n. Выведите получившиеся числа с помощью console.log. Выведите результаты их сравнения >, <, ≥, ≤, ===, ≠ с помощью

```
console.log.
```

Проверка результата
Для проверки подставляйте разные значения переменных a, b и n и проверяйте получившийся результат. Сравнения должны давать соответствующий результат true или false в зависимости от получившихся дробных частей.

Примеры для проверки:

```
Для a = 13.123456789, b = 2.123, n = 5 дробные части: 12345, 12300.
Для a = 13.890123, b = 2.891564, n = 2 дробные части: 89, 89.
Для a = 13.890123, b = 2.891564, n = 3 дробные части: 890, 891.
```

Критерии оценки
Для любых значений a, b и n корректно вычисляются дробные части и выводятся результаты сравнения.

Comment: похоже на задачу с codewars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сам решил таким способом

```
        function getInteger(a,n) {
           let z = ((a - Math.floor(a)) * Math.pow(10, n));   
                 return Math.trunc(z)
                 }
```

Comment: _`a - Math.floor(a)`_ - бррррррр

Comment: это плохо? как по мне это самое правильное решение получилось. просто отнимаю дробное число от целого и затем умножаю на 10 в степени n. Тем самым перевел дробное число в целое. Ну а дальше уже сравнение и т.д.

Comment: Оно заменяется более красивым `a % 1`. В целом решение вроде хорошее, но я не уверен, не может ли умножение на степень 10 внести дополнительную погрешность, поэтому в своём ответе использовал другой вариант.

Comment: как обходите `getInteger(5.1, 1) = 0` ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function fr(x, n) {
  var s = x.toFixed(100)
  return s.substr(s.indexOf(".") + 1, n).padEnd(n, 0)
}

for (var n = 1; n <= 16; ++n) {
  console.log(fr(12.34567890132456, n))
}

for (var n = 98; n <= 102; ++n) {
  console.log(fr(12.34567890132456, n))
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
.as-console-row-code { word-break: break-word; word-wrap: break-word; overflow-wrap: break-word; }
```

А вообще, дробная часть числа получается так:

```js
var x = 12.3456789012345
console.log(x % 1)
```

Comment: 1.4%1 = 0.3999999999999999

Comment: @br3t, и что? Так и должно быть. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJoYN.png

Comment: да, потому, наверное, лучше всего работать с этим как со строками

Comment: @br3t, но по условию в вопросе уже даны числа, а не строки. Если есть строка, то из моего решения достаточно выкинуть `var s = x.toFixed(100)`

Comment: да, но для точности получается необходимость преобразовать числа в строку, а в выводе опять вернуть числа. Решения из вашего скрина не пройдут тесты

Comment: @br3t, с какого перепуга для вывода вернуть числа? Я вывожу строку. Более того, у чисел не может быть лидирующих нулей.

Comment: "Выведите получившиеся числа". Понятно, что для `console.log` это не критично, строки там или числа

Comment: @br3t, если нужны числа, то что выводить для 1.001?

Comment: Зависит от `n`. При n < 3 выводить 0

Comment: @br3t, а при 3 и больше?

Comment: n=3 -> 1; n=4 -> 10; n=5 ->100 etc

Comment: Вот тут тоже получилось `fr(5.1,1) = "0"`

Answer (score 0):

Получить дробную часть числа можно так:

```
let number = 5.234
console.log(number.toString().split('.')[1])
```

Дальше сами

Comment: А если `number = 0.0000001`?

Comment: @Yaant всё равно будет работать, у этого числа дробная часть `0000001` или ты хочешь сказать, что у чисел `0.1` и `0.0001` одинаковая дробная часть? =)

Comment: (0.0000001).toString() = "1e-7" со всеми вытекающими

Comment: @br3t не знал об этой особенности js, сегодня попробую =)

Answer (score 0):

Вычислить дробную часть числа можно отняв от этого числа его целую часть. Округлить результат до определённого количества знаков после запятой можно с помощью метода toFixed() и в скобках нужное количество знаков после запятой.

```js
var number = 123.456789; // наше исходное число
var fractionalPart = number - Math.floor(number); // его дробная часть
fractionalPart -= 0.0005;
fractionalPart -= 5 * Math.pow(10, -4); // 4 - число на единицу больше количества знаков, которые нужно оставить после запятой.
var result = fractionalPart.toFixed(3); // дробная часть, округлённая до 3 знаков после запятой
console.log(result); // 0.456
```

Comment: _`number - Math.floor(number)`_ - бррррр

Comment: Кстати, округлять не просили, а в примерах явно видно truncate: 13.123456789 => 12345

Comment: Это не я округлил, а метод toFixed() :) Сам я против. Но если отрезультата отнять 5 единиц самого младшего разряда, то получится без округления.

Comment: вот из-за этого toFixed я и решился задать тут вопрос этот) он явно не поможет в этой задаче из-за своей любви к округлению дробной части)

Comment: Поможет! (но не явно) :) Я переделал ответ.

Comment: Вычитание, скорее всего, может погрешность создать. Хотя я не очень уверен.

Comment: @AndrewWander, а нет возможности прочитать число как строку и просто вырезать нужный кусок? Нужны именно числа?

Answer (score 0):

Сделал с помощью объектов Math.

```
let a = 13.123456789;
let b = 2.123;
let n = 5;

/*
let a = 13.890123; 
let b = 2.891564; 
let n = 2;

let a = 13.890123;
let b = 2.891564; 
let n = 3;
*/

// целая часть
let aFloor = Math.floor(a);
let bFloor = Math.floor(b);

//дробная часть
let aFract = (a % 1);
let bFract = (b % 1);

let aFractNormalized = Math.round(
aFract * Math.pow(10, n)
);
let bFractNormalized = Math.round(
bFract * Math.pow(10, n)
);

console.log('Для a = ', a);
console.log('Для b = ', b);
console.log('Целая часть a: ', aFloor);
console.log('Целая часть b: ', bFloor);
console.log('Дробная часть a: ', aFract);
console.log('Дробная часть b: ', bFract);
console.log('Нормализованная дробная часть a:', aFractNormalized);
console.log('Нормализованная дробная часть b:', bFractNormalized);
//результаты сравнения >, <, ≥, ≤, ===, ≠
console.log('a > b', aFractNormalized > bFractNormalized);
console.log('a < b', aFractNormalized < bFractNormalized);
console.log('a >= b', aFractNormalized >= bFractNormalized);
console.log('a <= b', aFractNormalized <= bFractNormalized);
console.log('a === b', aFractNormalized === bFractNormalized);
console.log('a ≠ b', aFractNormalized !== bFractNormalized);
```

Comment: Вместо .round я бы использовал .trunc: он не округляет.